# How to build multiple configurations?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, msbuild

I want to build the SLN from command line. I have tried

```
D:\>msbuild MySolution.sln
```

Problem is that it fails to build project `C` which is targeted for x86, while projects `A` and `B` are built right. It gives error:

> Project "D:.....\MySolution.sln" (1) is building
>   "D:.....\MySolution\ToolC\C.csproj" (4) on node 0 (default
>   targets).
> C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Microsoft.Common.targets(539,9):
>   error : The OutputPath property is not set for this project.  Please
>   check to make sure that you have specified a valid
>   Configuration/Platform combination.  Configuration='Debug' 
>   Platform='AnyCPU'
> Done Building Project
>   "D:.....\MySolution\ToolC\C.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Why is it building `C` for target "Any CPU"?

**Details**
I have 1 SLN file with 3 C# projects, say, A, B, C.

Projects `A` and `B` are default targeted for "Any CPU". Project `C` is targeted for "x86"

Here is the content of SLN file (only `Global` section):

```
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
        Debug|x86 = Debug|x86
        Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
        Release|x86 = Release|x86
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {AAAAAAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAA}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {AAAAAAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAA}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {AAAAAAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAA}.Debug|x86.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {AAAAAAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAA}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {AAAAAAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAA}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {AAAAAAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAA}.Release|x86.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {BBBBBBBB-BBBB-BBBB-BBBB-BBBBBBBBBBBB}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {BBBBBBBB-BBBB-BBBB-BBBB-BBBBBBBBBBBB}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {BBBBBBBB-BBBB-BBBB-BBBB-BBBBBBBBBBBB}.Debug|x86.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {BBBBBBBB-BBBB-BBBB-BBBB-BBBBBBBBBBBB}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {BBBBBBBB-BBBB-BBBB-BBBB-BBBBBBBBBBBB}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {BBBBBBBB-BBBB-BBBB-BBBB-BBBBBBBBBBBB}.Release|x86.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {CCCCCCCC-CCCC-CCCC-CCCC-CCCCCCCCCCCC}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {CCCCCCCC-CCCC-CCCC-CCCC-CCCCCCCCCCCC}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {CCCCCCCC-CCCC-CCCC-CCCC-CCCCCCCCCCCC}.Debug|x86.ActiveCfg = Debug|x86
        {CCCCCCCC-CCCC-CCCC-CCCC-CCCCCCCCCCCC}.Debug|x86.Build.0 = Debug|x86
        {CCCCCCCC-CCCC-CCCC-CCCC-CCCCCCCCCCCC}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {CCCCCCCC-CCCC-CCCC-CCCC-CCCCCCCCCCCC}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {CCCCCCCC-CCCC-CCCC-CCCC-CCCCCCCCCCCC}.Release|x86.ActiveCfg = Release|x86
        {CCCCCCCC-CCCC-CCCC-CCCC-CCCCCCCCCCCC}.Release|x86.Build.0 = Release|x86
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

And, here is the CSPROJ file content for project `C`:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    ....
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86' ">
    <OutputPath>bin\x86\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
    ....
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x86' ">
    <OutputPath>bin\x86\Release\</OutputPath>
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
    ....
  </PropertyGroup>
```

I also tried this, but the problem remains same:

```
<Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">x86</Platform>
```

Comment: any final solution with full source code ? Can I read ProjectConfigurationPlatforms programatically ?

Comment: Sorry, but I do not have any working solution to share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your default configuration of C project is **anycpu|debug** but there isn't a propertygroup section for that config in what you've show or default values, therefore no **Outputpath** property exists. Fix that, either add some defaults or a new property group.
Then make sure you've got the right configuration setup in **Build->Configuration Manager** in VS.

Its hard to know what actual targets you want to build under what configuration in your sln but this sln works for me with standard csprojs (console):

```
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
        Debug|x86 = Debug|x86
        Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
        Release|x86 = Release|x86
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {AAAAAAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAA}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {AAAAAAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAA}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {AAAAAAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAA}.Debug|x86.ActiveCfg = Debug|x86
        {AAAAAAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAA}.Debug|x86.Build.0 = Debug|x86
        {AAAAAAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAA}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|x86
        {AAAAAAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAA}.Release|x86.ActiveCfg = Release|x86
        {BBBBBBBB-BBBB-BBBB-BBBB-BBBBBBBBBBBB}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {BBBBBBBB-BBBB-BBBB-BBBB-BBBBBBBBBBBB}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {BBBBBBBB-BBBB-BBBB-BBBB-BBBBBBBBBBBB}.Debug|x86.ActiveCfg = Debug|x86
        {BBBBBBBB-BBBB-BBBB-BBBB-BBBBBBBBBBBB}.Debug|x86.Build.0 = Debug|x86
        {BBBBBBBB-BBBB-BBBB-BBBB-BBBBBBBBBBBB}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|x86
        {BBBBBBBB-BBBB-BBBB-BBBB-BBBBBBBBBBBB}.Release|x86.ActiveCfg = Release|x86
        {CCCCCCCC-CCCC-CCCC-CCCC-CCCCCCCCCCCC}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {CCCCCCCC-CCCC-CCCC-CCCC-CCCCCCCCCCCC}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {CCCCCCCC-CCCC-CCCC-CCCC-CCCCCCCCCCCC}.Debug|x86.ActiveCfg = Debug|x86
        {CCCCCCCC-CCCC-CCCC-CCCC-CCCCCCCCCCCC}.Debug|x86.Build.0 = Debug|x86
        {CCCCCCCC-CCCC-CCCC-CCCC-CCCCCCCCCCCC}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|x86
        {CCCCCCCC-CCCC-CCCC-CCCC-CCCCCCCCCCCC}.Release|x86.ActiveCfg = Release|x86
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

I had to add targets for "Any CPU" to the csproj thru configuration manager, i can give you those to if that helps.
This builds fine using either:

```
msbuild Your.sln /t:Rebuild /p:Platform="Any CPU"
```

or

```
msbuild ConsoleApplication1.sln /t:Rebuild /p:Platform=x86
```

If you wanted to build both platforms..
You could add a target to your csproj like:

```
<Target Name="AllPlatforms" Outputs="$(TargetPath)">
    <ItemGroup>
      <AllPlatforms Include="AnyCPU,x86"/>
    </ItemGroup>

    <Message Text="Building All platform %(AllPlatforms.Identity)"/>
    <MSBuild Projects="$(MSBuildProjectFullPath)" Properties="Platform=%(AllPlatforms.Identity)"/>

  </Target>
```

But it think youd have to call msbuild on your cspoj rather than sln. So you might as well
call it twice using an external script. Its all a bit hacky. Besides you need to alter the output paths for each platform to get the output.

Comment: Okay. But my real target is x86. How will adding **anycpu|debug** make sure that x86 gets built? Can you please explain?

Comment: I tried your suggestion also. It built anycpu target, not x86.

Comment: From your example, I think, I have to invoke msbuild twice, one for x86 and other for Any CPU. I knew this, but, the build machine scripts are not in my control currently. My question is - can the build be done in one shot only? I am feeling the answer is no. :(